# How can I set UTF8 and start H2O Flow UI via R?

Tags: r, h2o

I would like to set UTF8 in H2O Flow UI.

In terminal, I can set UTF8 and open H2O Flow UI.

```
java -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 h2o.jar
```

but I normally use R.
How can I set UTF8 and start H2O Flow UI via R?

I tried that following.

```
options(encoding = "utf-8")
h2o.init()
```

and

```
h2o.init(extra_classpath = "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8")
```

It runs, but doesn't set UTF8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your option to the `jvm_custom_args` argument, not `extra_classpath`, as in `h2o.init(jvm_custom_args = "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8")`